# Signals and Slot access specifier in Qt

Tags: qt, signals, slots

I am incredibly confused about the concept of access specifiers for Signals and Slots in Qt.

While researching, I stumble upon many answers that suggest the following:

**"signals should only be emitted by the class who owns the signal."**

However, immediately after the above suggestion, they also say something opposite:

**"if signals were really protected or private, you would not be able to connect to them using the pointer-to-member function syntax. To make such connections possible thy need to be public"**

I even tried looking up the Qt6 documentation:

**"Signals are public access functions and can be emitted from anywhere, but we recommend to only emit them from the class that defines the signal and its subclasses."**

I am truly confused at this point. Therefore, I have a couple of questions that I would highly appreciate it if someone can answer for me:

1- Is it required for Qt signals to be public or not? (Why does MOC make signals public after compilation?)

2- If it is not required for signals to be public, then what is the benefit of having them private?

3- If it is required for signals to be public, then why can slots have any access specifier?

4- Do access specifiers effect function-pointers at all in the connect method for signals and slots?

---------------------------------------------------

Comment: As already told you on another forum treat signals and slots as normal functions. If a signal is private/protected how should it be accessible from outside the class the pass the function pointer to the QObject::connect() function? Since a lot of slots are often connected inside it's class where they are defined it also makes sense to have them protected or private.

Comment: Okay. Now I understand the part about slots. However, even if I decide to make a signal private/protected, the MOC in Qt turns it into a public signal anyway. Why does MOC do that?

Comment: Because, as already said you want to be able to connect them from outside of the class where they're defined.